# How do I get the Status Code and Header data from a HttpResponseData object?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I currently have a Blazor Client (Wasm) with a ASP.NET Core Web API. (Both deployed to Azure)

The ASP.NET Core Web API returns a IActionResult, which converts into a HttpResponseMessage in my BlazorClient.

I wanted to swap out my ASP.NET Core Web API with a Azure Function HTTP Trigged.

The Azure Function is .Net 5.  (I had to do this since all of my other projects in the solution is .Net 5).

Since the function is written in .Net 5, a HttpResponseData Object is returned.

In my HttpResponseData object I have Status Code which I want to test in my Client, Header Data, which I need to access (Total Count), plus the Body that has my list of data.

When I call the Azure Function from my Blazor Client, I can't access the Header data.

I was also having issues getting the Body data as well when I use the _httpClient.GetAsync method.

The best I could do was use the _httpClient.GetStringAsync method. That get me my data from the body.

But, I want the Status Code and Header Data as well.

See the code below.

```
        public async Task<string> GetVpbDelegatesAsync2(int? pageNo, int? pageSize, string searchText)
        {
            var requestUri = $"{RequestUri.VpbDelegates}?pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&searchText={searchText}";

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);

            //This line throws an exception. If I comment it out. I get my Body data
            var total = response.Headers.GetValues("X-TotalCount").First();

            return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
        }
```

So my questions are:

- How can I get that Status Code?
- How can I get my Body Data?
- How can I get my Header Data
- Does anyone know of any demos / code examples with a client that calls a Azure Function that returns HttpResponseData. (I can't find any examples.)

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Just for those keep track at home:
I am able to get the Status Code, but I still can't get the Header Data.  I made the same call in PostMan and Header data is there.

Edit 2: I figured out how to get my data out of the Body / Content.  But still not getting Header data.

Comment: I thought `HttpClient` returned a `HttpResponseMessage`?

Comment: It does.  However, the Azure Function returns a HttpResponseData.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpResponseData` object is only in the context of the function code. Your `HttpClient` object would still return `HttpResponseMessage` like @Greg mentioned.